# Convert varchar(max) to varbinary(max)

Tags: sql-server, converters

I need to update a column using the convert binary function but it's throwing an error.

This is my query:

```
update DocumentOnline
set FileData = CONVERT(VARBINARY(max), FileData, 0x255044462D312E340A25E2E3CFD30A322030206F626A0A3C3C2F4C656E6774682034392F46696C7465722F466C6174654465636F64653E3E73747265616D0A789C2BE4720AE1323653B03030530849E1720DE10AE42A54305430004208999CABA01F9166A8E092AF10C80500EAA209F20A656E6473747265616D0A656E646F626A0A342030206F626A0A3C3C2F5265736F75726365733C3C2F584F626A6563743C3C2F586631203120) 
where ClientId = '54528' and EndDate = '201607'
```

and this is the error :

> Argument data type varbinary(max) is invalid for argument 3 of convert function.

I'm a beginner in SQL - what am I missing ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Product specific functionality used...)

Comment: @jarlh im using sql server

Comment: You're missing [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187928). `CONVERT` has three arguments, but you're not using it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using wrong Syntax for CONVERT

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx

```
-- Syntax for CONVERT:  
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

try to use this

```
update DocumentOnline
set FileData = CONVERT(VARBINARY(max),  0x255044462D312E340A25E2E3CFD30A322030206F626A0A3C3C2F4C656E6774682034392F46696C7465722F466C6174654465636F64653E3E73747265616D0A789C2BE4720AE1323653B03030530849E1720DE10AE42A54305430004208999CABA01F9166A8E092AF10C80500EAA209F20A656E6473747265616D0A656E646F626A0A342030206F626A0A3C3C2F5265736F75726365733C3C2F584F626A6563743C3C2F586631203120) 
where ClientId = '54528' and EndDate = '201607'
```

Answer (score 3):

If data type of `FileData` is `VARBINARY(MAX)` just use this:

```
update DocumentOnline
set FileData = 0x255044462D312E340A25E2E3CFD30A322030206F626A0A3C3C2F4C656E6774682034392F46696C7465722F466C6174654465636F64653E3E73747265616D0A789C2BE4720AE1323653B03030530849E1720DE10AE42A54305430004208999CABA01F9166A8E092AF10C80500EAA209F20A656E6473747265616D0A656E646F626A0A342030206F626A0A3C3C2F5265736F75726365733C3C2F584F626A6563743C3C2F586631203120
where ClientId = '54528' and EndDate = '201607'
```